# Fail loading database data in Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android, sql, singleton

I can't find exactly where I have my problem or why But my app seems o crash every time it tries to search for data in the database. Why does this happen? On second thought, I think I might have messed up on MySingleton.class, but I'm not sure how.

UPDATE
It now does not crash, but still doesn't load the data from my database..

UPDATE 2
I get this error in my URL

```html
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /storage/ssd1/078/5480078/public_html/denuncias/Connection.php on line 9
error
```

Connection.php

```html
<?php
$server_name = "localhost";
$user_name = "id5480078_denuncias";
$password = "smoothcriminal1";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $user_name, $password) or die ('Server '. mysql_error());
$database_name= 'id5480078_denuncias';
mysqli_select_db($database_name) or die('error');
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>

UPDATE 3 Connection.php was fixed, but nnow the data isnt loading in the app.
```

### Error Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo, PID: 25122
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.show()' on a null object reference
        at co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.Main2Activity.getSqlDetails(Main2Activity.java:58)
        at co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.Main2Activity.access$000(Main2Activity.java:25)
        at co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.Main2Activity$1.onClick(Main2Activity.java:48)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5714)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22589)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

### Main2Activity.class :

```
package co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.R;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView result;
EditText phone;
Button search;
String number;
private ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getSqlDetails();
        }
    });
}

private void getSqlDetails() {
    String url= "https://luisalonsoriveraibarra.000webhostapp.com/denuncias/read.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    pd.hide();
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = jsonobject.getString("id");
                            String price = jsonobject.getString("price");
                            String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
                            String phone = jsonobject.getString("phone");

                            result.setText(" ID -"+id+"\n Price -"+price+"\n Name -"+name+"\n Phone -"+phone);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(error != null){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

    );
    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
}
```

### MySingleton.class:

```
package co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo;

import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Created by Luis Alonso on 17/7/2018.
 */

public class MySingleton {

    private static MySingleton instance = null;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    //a private constructor so no instances can be made outside this class
    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    //Everytime you need an instance, call this
    //synchronized to make the call thread-safe
    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context applicationContext) {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new MySingleton(applicationContext);

        return instance;
    }

    //Initialize this or any other variables in probably the Application class
    public void init(Context context) {}

    public RequestQueue addToRequestQueue(StringRequest stringRequest) {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
}
```

### read.php:

```
include_once("Connection.php");

$query="SELECT * FROM data";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) == true){
    $data[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize progress dialog first before using it.

```
pd = new ProgressDialog (this);
```

Answer to updated Question:-

The method

```
mysqli_select_db(connection, dbname);
```

accepts two parameters. So do like this -

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $database_name);
```

Comment: I had a progress dialog at first and it was a continuous loop

Comment: You are using  pd.hide(); inside your getSqlDetails() method. So, you have to first initialize it.

Comment: ok forgot about that, now the problem is that Im not getting any data from my database. That is why I had a continuous loop

Comment: See the result of the url. Is it returning a correct response?? If yes, plz add that too in ques. Also mention the new error that you are getting in logcat.

Comment: I get Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /storage/ssd1/078/5480078/public_html/denuncias/Connection.php on line 9
error... I will update my answer with my Connection.php file

Comment: So, it seems there is an error in your Connection.php file.

Comment: Now, the response is successful. So, plz accept my answer.

Comment: That fixed the issue with connection, now the problem is that the data isnt loading in the application

Comment: Please help me with that

Comment: This problem is solved & u should accept this. For another issue you should frame a different question regarding that by properly mentioning your database structure and activity in which data is retrieving.

Comment: Raj, if you read the question carefully I put the code of my activity and others.

Comment: PS The data is returning successfully via an echo to the web browser, not he app. So I guess now the problem is in Android

Comment: But thats another issue. According to the rules of the community you have to ask a different question for different issue. Moreover, I have already solved 2 of your questions. So, plz make a new question for that issue. Also, accept my answer as it worked for you. Check the tick icon on left side under my answer to accept it.